# Does the anime of Denpa Kyoushi add anything new?

Tags: denpa-kyoushi

I've kept up to date with the manga of Denpa Kyoushi, which I've really enjoyed - but I've heard bad things about the animé. Mostly about the low standard of art and not doing the manga justice in some scenes.

I did enjoy the manga, but not enough to watch the anime - unless there is any significant difference between them (in which case, I'd like to watch those segments so I have the *complete* story).

Is there anything major in the anime that is different to the manga? or any new characters?

Comment: There are no major differences. Only one minor difference, where the class rep in the first school is introduced to take place of the shoplifter role, which was played by Ichou academy chairwoman in the manga.

Answer (score 1):

Differences I noticed in manga vol 1:

- when Junichiro first met Minako, he asked her whether she's from choir club after she finished singing.
- There's a replacement teacher in Junichiro's retirement speech. Junichiro at first attempt to just give normal speech, but due to that teacher that orders the students to follow the rules, Junichiro instead uses his 'special' speech.
- Junichiro gets paper with signature of his students after being fired.
- After Junichiro was fired from the first school he taught, his former colleague from Jenewa came to ask him to go there to work with her. However, he turned the offer down just like when the chairwoman recruits him. Before he started teaching in Hiiragi School.
- Since Junichiro's colleague came and went back to Jenewa after she failed to recruit him, there's no 'playing hide-and-seek' big scene that the chairwoman and Suzune tracking down Kagami.